# Как сохранить заданные параметры в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть программа, в ней есть включении и отключение звука с кнопки (UI-buttons), через AudioListner.

Подскажите, как можно сделать, чтобы при включении/отключении звука, выбор запоминался и не изменялся при последующем запуске программы.

Нужен какой-нибудь универсальный метод, чтобы его можно было применять так-же и на другие задачи, такие как - выбор языка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делаете сохраняемый параметр, например, у вас есть

```
private enum Language
{
 Russian,
 English
}
```

при смене языка сохраняете в переменную `Language selectedLanguage=Language.Russian; curentLanguage=selectedLanguage;` (можете статическую сделать или как угодно), при выходе из игры сохраняете `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("saveLanguage", (int)curentLanguage);` при запуске игры проверяете наличие сохранения и при его наличии копируете сохраненные данные:

```
if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("saveLanguage"))
{
  (int)curentLanguage = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("saveLanguage");
}
```

[Вот ссылка на справку по PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html), и ещё [вот тут почитайте, в этой же статье есть про сериализацию в xml файл](https://habr.com/post/163071/),  если вам PlayerPrefs не подойдет.